# Oracle SQL Rank

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

I have this table as per below:

```
[Table A][1]

B_NUMBER_COUNTRY    OUTGOING_CARRIER    MINUTES
CAN                 A                  1,045.71 
CAN                 B                      7.98 
CAN                 C                    973.52 
FRA                 A                    566.19 
FRA                 B                    521.52 
FRA                 C                     27.03 
FRA                 D                    549.14 
FRA                 E                      0.21 
USA                 A                     32.57 
USA                 B                    303.17 
USA                 C                  9,837.53 
USA                 D                      3.91 
USA                 E                      0.07 
USA                 F                  2,469.00 
USA                 G                     67.68 
USA                 H                      0.37 
USA                 I                    933.72
```

I need to rank `b_number_country` based on the sum of minutes.

In the above case, the total minutes for USA is 13K, CAN is 2K and FRA is 1.6K. So the ranking should be USA - 1, CAN - 2 and FRA - 3. By adding the rank column, it should be showing as per below:

```
[Table A (rank)][2]

B_NUMBER_COUNTRY    OUTGOING_CARRIER    MINUTES  RANK
CAN                 A                  1,045.71  2
CAN                 B                      7.98  2
CAN                 C                    973.52  2
FRA                 A                    566.19  3
FRA                 B                    521.52  3
FRA                 C                     27.03  3
FRA                 D                    549.14  3
FRA                 E                      0.21  3
USA                 A                     32.57  1
USA                 B                    303.17  1
USA                 C                  9,837.53  1
USA                 D                      3.91  1
USA                 E                      0.07  1
USA                 F                  2,469.00  1
USA                 G                     67.68  1
USA                 H                      0.37  1
USA                 I                    933.72  1
```

I am unable to get the right query to do this. Every attempt, it includes both `b_number_country` and `outgoing_carrier` as part of the ranking.

Comment: To clarify the code comment about DENSE_RANK in dnoeth's Answer, and Gordon's comment to that answer:  What do you want to display for "Rank" if there are ties? Suppose USA and France are tied for first; do you want them both to show rank 1 and Canada to show 3?  Or do you want USA = 1, France = 1, Canada = 2? Or perhaps (although less likely), chose one of USA and France to be 1, the other one to be 2, and Canada to be 3? The choice for 1 and 2 to be random, or based on a secondary sort (for example, alphabetically, or by number of carriers, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

Edited based on comment:

You need two steps, calculate the sum of the minutes first and then rank them:

```
SELECT ...,
   DENSE_RANK()
   OVER (ORDER BY sumMinutes DESC) -- must be DENSE_RANK
FROM
 (
   SELECT b_number_country, interval_of_day, outgoing_carrier, 
      SUM (call_duration)/60 AS Minutes, 
      SUM (call_count) AS attempt, 
      SUM (answered_count) AS answered, 
      SUM (seizure_count) AS seizure, 
      SUM(start_call_count) AS Count_X, 
      SUM(ner_count) AS NER_COUNT,
      SUM(SUM (call_duration)/60) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY B_NUMBER_COUNTRY) AS sumMinutes 
   FROM bm_archived_cdr 
   WHERE call_direction = 'O' 
     AND call_date = DATE '2016-04-21' 
   GROUP BY b_number_country, interval_of_day, outgoing_carrier
 ) dt;
```

Comment: If the OP wants a separate rank for countries that have the same sum, then s/he would include `b_number_country` in the `order by` in the outer query.

Comment: hi...appreciate the feedback so far. I have incorporated the above in my actual query and so far no luck.

Comment: SELECT b_number_country, interval_of_day, outgoing_carrier, SUM (call_duration)/60 AS Minutes, SUM (call_count) AS attempt, SUM (answered_count) AS answered, SUM (seizure_count) AS seizure, SUM(start_call_count) as Count_X, SUM(ner_count) as NER_COUNT,              dense_rank() over (order by sumMinutes desc) ( select B_NUMBER_COUNTRY, OUTGOING_CARRIER,
      sum(call_duration) over (partition by B_NUMBER_COUNTRY) as sumMinutes from bm_archived_cdr )  WHERE call_direction = 'O' and call_date = to_date('2016-04-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD') group by b_number_country, interval_of_day, outgoing_carrier;

Comment: the above is the query i am executing

Comment: hi..it works. Great job and your guide is much appreciated. Thanks much.